# Using Bootstrap 3 meteor

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I tried installing using both these smart packages:

https://github.com/eprochasson/bootstrap3-less
https://github.com/reywood/meteor-bootstrap3-sass

I get this error for both of them:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/sources/git.js:158
hrow "There was a problem checking out " + self.checkoutType + ": " + (self.co
                                                                    ^
There was a problem checking out tag: v1.9.2
```

I downloaded the bootstrap source files and added them to lib folder under my root. It didn't work. I get the error:

```
W20140126-13:49:20.210(2)? (STDERR) /Users/emrekenci/mytestapp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:186
W20140126-13:49:20.211(2)? (STDERR) }).run();
W20140126-13:49:20.211(2)? (STDERR)    ^
W20140126-13:49:20.213(2)? (STDERR) Error: Bootstrap requires jQuery
```

I tried putting the files under my root folder and I get the same error.

I don't know if I get this error because files under lib&root are loaded before jQuery or because Bootstrap requires jQuery >v1.9 and meteor comes with v1.8.2

Comment: For reference, the correct way to install those packages is with `mrt add bootstrap3-less` or `mrt add bootstrap3-sass`.

Comment: The question says I tried installing those and got the error which is also in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misread your question. Thought you might have tried to install them in some other way. Not sure why I thought that.

Comment: I used mrt add bootstrap3-less or mrt add bootstrap3-sass. Meteorite is working fine, I installed other packages with it before. But got the error in the question when trying to install these two packages. Do you have any idea why I might have gotten those?

Comment: Full disclosure, I created the bootstrap3-sass package. I can't imagine why it would cause that error to occur. The only dependency it has is on the `scss` meteorite package. As you said, meteor includes jQuery by default, so I didn't make that a dependency. There might be something in your `smart.json` or `smart.lock` files that would shed some light on this. Could you create a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) with their contents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you have a `Error: Bootstrap requires jQuery` error is because you are loading the files in your root folder, which causes them to be loaded on both the client and the server. To fix this, add the bootstrap files to `/client/lib` instead.

However, the installation of the smart packages should work, if you have meteorite correctly installed.